# Docker-compose for Spring Boot adaptation for different environements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring boot application running using docker, it works perfectly for my development in local but I want to deploy my app on a dev server using the same docker.

The problem is that I have different `application.yaml` depending on the environment, like `application-local.yaml` and `application-dev.yaml`

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    network_mode: "host"
    container_name: hebergement-backend
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/hebergement/data:/var/lib/hebergement/data
```

And the dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11 AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY api /build/api/
COPY commons /build/commons/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/api/target/*.jar app.jar
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/commons/target/*.jar commons.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=local","/app.jar"]
```

In the Dockerfile, I have my local profile set.
Is there a way to change the active profile without editing the Dockerfile, like using a parameter or an env variable?

Answer (score 2):

In `Dockerfile`, define the variable representing the environment passed to the `jar`:

```
ARG ENVIRONMENT
...
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=$ENVIRONMENT","/app.jar"]
```

Now use the `build` command for `docker-compose` and pass the variable using `--build-arg:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=local
```

Another way is using the environment file, read more at [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [active Spring profile(s)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles) using the Spring `spring.profiles.active` property.

In general, you can [set arbitrary Spring properties with environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding).  That means you can set a `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable at deployment time to pick a different profile.  In Compose:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/hebergement/data:/var/lib/hebergement/data
    environment:
      - SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES=dev
    # (do not need network_mode: or container_name: in normal use)
```

Since you can set any individual property this way, this also means you can set specific things without putting them in an `application.yml` file.
For container deployments, I've found this approach to be much more flexible than Spring profile files: you can change the property setting at deployment time, without needing to find the properties file in your source tree and rebuild the jar and image.

For example, let's say your application needs a database.  In development, you might set up `application.yml` to point to a database on `localhost`, but in pre-deployment testing, you might want to run everything in a single Compose setup.  You can configure the Spring JDBC properties directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=passw0rd
  backend:
    ...
    environment:
      # This URL will not work with network_mode: host
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgres://db/dbname
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=passw0rd
      # Probably don't need an alternate profile
```

Comment: This is the best alternative indeed. He doesn't need to pass any environment arg in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `entrypoint.sh` script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE /app.jar
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
ENV PROFILE local
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+rx /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  backend:
    network_mode: "host"
    container_name: hebergement-backend
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      PROFILE: "local"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/hebergement/data:/var/lib/hebergement/data
```

Comment: `ARG` doesn't seem like the right answer here; it would mean you'd need to rebuild your image if you want to deploy it in a different environment.